# Identify this A-B-C children's song in Dutch

Tags: toddler, language-development, music

My wife remembers the first couple of verses of a children's alphabet song (in Dutch) from her childhood and would like to find the lyrics of the complete song. She remembers singing this at least 22 years ago, and had it on a cassette back then.

I googled several parts of these lyrics and searched through multiple sites that collect children's songs, but nothing useful came up.

Here are the Dutch lyrics that she remembers and the literal translations to English:
(note that this song simply lists examples of words of the right letters, which is lost in translation. Also the rhythm and rhyming scheme are not there in my English version.)

```
A is de A van aap en aal                                    A is the A of monkey and eel
Aapje, mijn schaapje, ik scheer je kaal                     Little monkey, my little sheep, I shave you bald
A van amandel en van azijn                                  A of almond and of vinegar
Jij mag de eerste letter zijn                               You can be the first letter

B is de B van beertje brom                                  B is the B of little brown bear
Beertje meneertje rom bom bom                               Little bear, little mister, hum dum dum
B is een boottocht op de zee                                B is a boatride on the sea
Jeeminee wij varen mee                                      Yikes, we're sailing along

C is een ceder, altijd groen                                C is a cedar, always green
Soms ook een centje of een citroen                          Also sometimes a penny or a lemon
C is een circus in de zon                                   C is a circus in the sun
Ik wou ik dat ik het alfabet al kon                         I wish I knew the alphabet already

Apen gapen, beren klauwen, al die letters door elkaar       Monkeys yawn, bears scratch, al these letters scrambled
Heus niet moeilijk te onthouden, A-B-C die zijn al klaar    Really not that difficult to remember, A-B-C are done already
*gesproken* We kennen al de letters: A, B, C                *spoken word* We already know the letters: A, B, C
*stilte om na te zeggen* A, B, C                            *silence so you can repeat* A, B, C
*gesproken* We gaan daarna verder met de letter D           *spoken word* We now continue with the letter D

D is mijn deken, warm en zacht                              D is my blanket, warm and soft
Een hele chique dame die nooit eens lacht                   A very posh lady who never laughs
Soms kan de D ook een ??? zijn                              A D can sometimes be a ???
Een donderende donder of een dolfijn                        A thundering thunder or a dolphin

En daarna komt altijd de E                                  And afterwards there is the E
Eendjes voeren met zijn twee                                Feeding ducks two by two
Ezel, kwezel, repelsteel                                    Donkey, pious person, rumpelstiltskin
Heb jij soms een E te veel?                                 Would you have an E to spare?
```

Is there anyone here who knows this song and can continue these lyrics?

Comment: We've reopened this for now, to get some feedback from the community as to whether this can be on topic here; please vote to close if you think it's not, or upvote/answer/etc. as usual if you think it is :)